# Как преобразовать JSON массив в JSON строку

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть JSON массив в таком виде.

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Name 1"},{"id":"2","name":"Name 2"}]
```

Раньше эти данные были на отдельной страничке и я получал данные таким способом

```
$.getJSON("searchshop.php", function(json){ 
    for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
       alert(json[i].id);
    }
});
```

Все работало хорошо, но сделал передачу не в файл а напрямую в обработчик то ничего не работает.
пробовал сделать так

```
respone = '<?php echo $json; ?>';
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(respone);
```

Выдает ошибку

```
VM11773:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0
```

Как мне преобразовать $json  в объект javascript ? что бы с ним можно было работать как с массивом.
Подозреваю что причина в том что что бы сработала parseJSON нужна строка json а не объект, но как преобразовать объект в строку не знаю.

Comment: `console.log(respone)` что виводит ?

Comment: выводит [{"id":"1","name":"Name 1"},{"id":"2","name":"Name 2"}]

Comment: так может у вас там и так массив ?) и не надо ничего никуда конвертировать ?

Comment: Почему тогда не могу посчитать количество объектов в массиве с помощью length ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
response = '<?php echo $json; ?>';
console.log("Type 'response'", typeof response);

try {
  console.log("Length of response", response.length);
} catch(err) {
  console.log("Error", err)
}
```

Не могли бы вы запустить данный код и показать логи?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте с использованием этого:

```
JSON.stringify();
```

Comment: сделал вот так respone = '<?php echo $json; ?>'; var obj = JSON.stringify(respone); var json = JSON.parse(obj); но теперь ругается на for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) Ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: может и есть) но результата нету

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо понять что вам приходит в respone, текст или массив. Если там массив, то ничего преобразовывать не надо, а если текст то используйте  JSON.parse();

```js
//Приходит массив
let resp = [{"id":"1","name":"Name 1"},{"id":"2","name":"Name 2"}];

for (i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
  console.log(resp[i])
}

//Приходит текст
let respText =  '[{"id":"1","name":"Name 1"},{"id":"2","name":"Name 2"}]'

let respJson = JSON.parse(respText);
for (i = 0; i < respJson.length; i++) {
  console.log(respJson[i])
}
```